# How to get the return from php to javascript?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call php from javascript and return an array from php to Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594411/call-php-from-javascript-and-return-an-array-from-php-to-javascript-function)

i am having an php code for verification of User in XML

For Eg: ValLogin.php

```
<?php
$userName =  $_REQUEST["username"];
$password =  $_REQUEST["password"];
$iCount = 0;
$loginArray = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file("Logintest.xml");
for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
    foreach($xml->Username[$i]->attributes() as $a => $b)
    {
        $loginArray[$iCount] = $b;
        $iCount++;
    }
    if($userName == $loginArray[0] && $password == $loginArray[1])
    {
        header("Location: EHP_Configuration.html");
        return ;
    }
    $iCount = 0;
}
echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>alert('asd')</SCRIPT>";
header("Location: Login.html");
?>
```

HTML

```
<form method = "post" action = "ValLogin.php">
</form>
```

echo does not work as expected. it directly shows redirect to Login

How can i get the message invalid username/Login?

Comment: Can you please also provide an example of Logintest.xml? Amongst other things the way you iterate through the xml doc seems  ...odd ;-)

Comment: Logintest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Users>
<Username User = "Admin" Password = "Password"/>
<Username User = "Client" Password = "Client" />
</Users>

Comment: Extending VolkerK's note, use `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) rather than looping. Looking up a user will take 1 line: `$xml->xpath("//Username[@User='$username' and @Password='$password']")`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send HTML/Data before sending the header, so you'll have to send the javascript-alert inside the "Login.html".

Besides that you really should embrace your Javascript code with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         alert('asd');
</script>
```