# How to pass value from JavaScript to PHP and get return of PHP back to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call php from javascript and return an array from php to Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594411/call-php-from-javascript-and-return-an-array-from-php-to-javascript-function)

How to pass value from JavaScript to PHP and get return of PHP back to JavaScript function?

I have an HTML page which will have JavaScript function which should call PHP (PHP is another file)

for example like

```
function JavaCallphp()
{
test = Validate.php
}
```

`test` is variable on JavaScript

`Validate.php` is the File which contain Validation code and returns the Bool Value.

I want to get true/false in `test` variable

Comment: Ankita/NewBie, are you actually reading the answers to your previous questions, eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594411/call-php-from-javascript-and-return-an-array-from-php-to-javascript-function (marked as dupe)? You still seem to have little understanding of the fundamental architecture of HTTP on the client and server side.