# How to pass value from javascript to php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am getting value via `JQuery` as something like this

```
var query= popURL.split('?');  
var dim= query[1].split('&'); 
var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value 
var id = dim[1].split('=')[1];
```

Now i want to send or get this `"id"` value into same `php` file. I think we can only get value on other `php` page using `get` method. I want to get value on same `php` file.

I think we can do with this using `AJAX` right?

If yes please give me some links or code how to get? I am newbie to `ajax`.

Comment: +1 yes, Ajax. So why not tag it as ajax, php & javascript, as opposed to mysql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass value from Javascript to PHP and get return of PHP back to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599675/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php-and-get-return-of-php-back-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery api documentation, in particular to the [jQuery.ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You'll find documentation and many useful examples. This is a piece of code from that page that does exactly what you've requested:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

(Of course you can also pass the data by simply using GET params and appending them to the url)

Answer (score 0):

well, if you only want to send that data to the server and you don't want to retrieve anything else and don't know or don't want to use ajax, a more simpler solution would be to attach the desired url on a hidden dom object. such as :
`<img src="http://my-host.com/my-script.php?id="+id style="display:none;"/>`

witch can be added to the dom in multiple ways.

If you want to use ajax, I recommend using a library such as jQuery, wich is optimized for cross-browser web apps. With jQuery, the syntax is very simple :
`$.get(
    "http://my-host.com/my-script.php",
    {"id" : id},
    function(data){
        // do something with the response
    }
);`

You could use "post" instead of "get" depending on your needs. I recommend you take a peak at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).