# make a php variable equal a javascript output

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass value from javascript to php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767498/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php-file)

would something like this work?

```
<script>
    var a;
    a = 5;
<?php
    $b = ?>a;
</script>
```

I am wondering if I can have javascript parsed by the client-side and have the output information be picked up by PHP as a variable that can be used elsewhere.

Comment: Use AJAX - see the duplicate question I linked.

Comment: Why don't you try it ? it's not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually have your JS parsed with PHP if you:

- configured your web server to parse .js files, or,
- gave your JS file a .php extension and configured the response header with the appropriate content type

e.g.:

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/javascript');?>
```

You'd also need to have a PHP include or at least the relevant code to populate the required variables.

Note it's best practice to not use PHP short-tags - your php.ini should be configured to not allow them. i.e., do this:

```
<?php echo %b %>
```

instead of this:

```
<? echo %b %>
```

Answer (score 1):

that way you cant. The file is first parsed by PHP on the server and then sent to the client-side, where the javascript is parsed.

Without ajax or other kind of requests, data is not sent back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't

```
<script>
    var a;
    a = 5;
<?php
    $b = ?>a;
</script>
```

on the contrary, you can do this.

```
<script>
    var a;
    a = <?echo $b?>; // $b will be the variable of a in javascript (client side) 
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, that gave an idea. I swear can't be pro active when criticizing other peoples questions, marking down the score doesn't help or make the situation any more productive than it could be.