# How to pass variable in php via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have java script  .
now i want to pass the variable and get output of this script.
I little confuse .how to do this??
My script is like this

```
function doGet(e) {

  var sourceText = 'hiren'
  if (e.parameter.q){
    sourceText = e.parameter.q;
  }

  var sourceLang = 'auto';
  if (e.parameter.source){
    sourceLang = e.parameter.source;
  }

  var targetLang = 'ja';
  if (e.parameter.target){
    targetLang = e.parameter.target;
  }

  /* Option 1 */

  var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(sourceText, sourceLang, targetLang)

  /* Option 2 */  

  var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" 
            + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);

  var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

  translatedText = result[0][0][0];

  var json = {
    'sourceText' : sourceText,
    'translatedText' : translatedText
  };

  // set JSONP callback
  var callback = 'callback';
  if(e.parameter.callback){
    callback = e.parameter.callback
  }

  // return JSONP
  return ContentService
           .createTextOutput(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(json) + ')')
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

for out put i try this php script but it does not work.
it is like this

```
<?php $myphotoid = "<script language='javascript'>translatedText</script>";
echo $myphotoid;
 ?>
```

but it does not give the output of the script.
all i want is to input here `var sourceText = 'hiren'` and get the output.
i do not understand how to do this??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass value from JavaScript to PHP and get return of PHP back to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599675/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php-and-get-return-of-php-back-to-javascrip)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call php from javascript and return an array from php to Javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594411/call-php-from-javascript-and-return-an-array-from-php-to-javascript-function)

Comment: are you people blind???/

Comment: You can't parse/execute JS within PHP (except sending (echoing) it to the browser, but then you won't be able to fetch it with PHP in the same request). Request -> PHP parser (on server) ->send to browser -> JS parser (in browser)

Comment: What are `LanguageApp`, `UrlFetchApp`, `ContentService`?

Comment: what about using Ajax/xhr? You would just call your php-script and your php-script would echo out the result. As dataformat you might want to use JSON which is easy to use and create - both in PHP and JS.

Comment: Maybe you could explain the flow? What are you trying to do and why? It's easier for us to come with suggestions if we get what you actually are trying to accomplish.