# Javascript call php function and receives back results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594411/call-php-from-javascript-and-return-an-array-from-php-to-javascript-function)provides sample code using obtaining a server file list as an example.  Here is the code I have used:

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>How to create form using jQuery UI</title>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $.get('getfilename.php', { dir : '/ajax1/' }, function(data) {
        // you should now have a json encoded PHP array

        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            alert('index ' + key + ' points to file ' + val);

        });
    }, 'json');
    alert ("ok");
});

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Get file names... </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

getfilename.php

```
$dir = $_REQUEST['dir'] ;
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir;

$filesArray = array(); 
$Counter = 0; 
$files = scandir($dir); 

foreach ($files as &$file) { 
    if ($file!='.' && $file!='..' ) { 
        $filesArray[$Counter] = $file; 
        echo $filesArray[$Counter].''; 
        $Counter++;
    }
} 

echo json_encode($filesArray);
```

My problem is that the javascript alert  `alert('index ' + key + ' points to file ' + val);` fails to display anything on the page.  The script is working because I get a response in the Firebug console log.

```
ajax.jsajax.phpindex.html["ajax.js","ajax.php","index.html"]
```

What I need to change on the script to return this information to the html page so that I can use the JSON for further processing ?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(data);` in your javascript console?  Are there any console errors?

Comment: Thanks Robbert  - I used Firebug and there are no errors shown in the Console section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your debug you broke the JSON output in PHP. So, remove:

```
echo $filesArray[$Counter].'';
```

Also, before any output, you should add JSON header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

At the end, your PHP file should look like this:

```
$dir = $_REQUEST['dir'] ;
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $dir;

$filesArray = array(); 
$files = scandir($dir); 

foreach ($files as &$file) { 
    if ($file!='.' && $file!='..' ) { 
        $filesArray[] = $file; 
    }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($filesArray);
```

Comment: Since he specifies the datatype `json` when he calls `$.get`, the `Content-Type` header is redundant.

Comment: Your chicken is older than the egg, Barmar. If he specified the PHP header, than he would not care about the `dataType` later on.

Comment: But he already has that in the code in his question, so it's not needed to fix the code.

Comment: Thanks skobaljic - the alerts in the loop now put out indices and values.  Brilliant !  Thanks also for the explanation and also for posting the corrected code.

Comment: You are welcome. You should also consider using [glob function](http://php.net/glob), it would return the array of files.